# What does preventDefault() prevent in drag & drop?

Tags: javascript, html

for example here is the drag and drop code from w3schools.com:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}  

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();    
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");     
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: It depends on the type of element that was dragged. If it is a `anchor` element, it will prevent following the `href` attribute value.

Comment: what about an <img> ?

Comment: HTML Standard -> [6.7.5 Drag-and-drop processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model)

Comment: [HTML Drag and Drop API (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

Comment: W3C Spec https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#dnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must cancel the default action for ondragenter and ondragover in order for ondrop to fire. In the case of a div, the default action is not to drop. This can be contrasted with the case of an input type=text element, where the default action is to drop. In order to allow a drag-and-drop action on a div, you must cancel the default action

Answer (score 0):

- Call `preventDefault()` to prevent the browser default handling of the
  data (default is open as link on drop)
- Get the dragged data with the    `dataTransfer.getData()` method. This    method will return any data that     was set to the 
  same type in the    `setData()` method